# Is the React + Redux integration require React.createClass only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got a react component, I would like to integrate the redux to that. So I have reference to the official document:
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

It seems that it only allow the `connect()` function is only work for the React.createClass, does it mean I can't use it in React.Components? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the exact same way. You just pass the component to it like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => dispatch(someFunc)
  }
}
const HelloWorld = ({ onClick }) => <div onClick={onClick}>Hello World</div>;

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HelloWorld);
```

It has an example of this on the link you provided.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions'
import Link from '../components/Link'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}

const FilterLink = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Link)
```

Link is a component.

What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know how to let the `HelloWorld` call the function in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: @DNB5brims Everything in `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` just gets passed in as props. I'v updated the example